# Dropdownmenu SELECTED value as per value return fromDB

Tags: php, javascript

All i am trying to do is to set the selected value of drop down menu according to the particular value returned from the database

like if person saved his gender as 'Male' and he wants to update his profile then the selected option shown on the Gender's dropdown llist should be 
shown as Male
cause if this doesn't happen 'Poor guy becomes a female due to this small problem in my code'
 KINDLY HELP!!!!!!!

MY Current Code:

```
<select name="Gender" id="Gender">
                  <option selected="selected"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Gender']; ?></option>
                  <option value="Male">Male</option>
                  <option value="Female">Female</option>
                </select>
```

The above code work fine but causes repitition of values in dropdown like
Male
Male
Female

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use an if statement in each  tag like below

```
<select name="Gender" id="Gender">         
              <option value="Male" <?php if($row_Recordset1['Gender']=='Male'){echo 'selected';}?>>Male</option>
              <option value="Female" <?php if($row_Recordset1['Gender']=='Female'){echo 'selected';}?>>Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what about for large values in dropdown like country lists..? is there no way to do it via javascripting

Answer (score 1):

make a loop

```
$gen=new array('male'=>"Male",'female'=>"Femele");
while(list($k,$v)=each($gen)){
      if($row_Recordset1['Gender']==$k){
               $sel="selected";
       else{
            $sel="";
       }
        echo "<option value='$k' $sel>$v</option>";
}
```

Comment: fetch all data in array then loop over it

Comment: is there no way to do it via javascripting